# "DataReader.GetFieldType(...) returned null" on Azure Website

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, ado.net

I have a website running on Azure.  I am pulling back data from a SQL Server database table that has a column of type "Geography".  This causes an error of "DataReader.GetFieldType(...) returned null

Sources on the web say that I have to include Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll which I have added to web.config and the bin folder but the error still occurs.  What am I missing?

Code:

```
    SqlConnection Connection = NewConnection();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, Connection);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Can you post your connection string (minus login information obviously)?

Comment: Connection String
    "Server=tcp:SERVER-NAME,1433;Database=DATABASE-NAME;User ID=SQL-USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=5;"

Comment: Have you added the reference to the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll in your project through 'add reference', or just added it to the bin folder manually?

Comment: <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

Answer (score 4):

We have experienced a number of problems with Microsoft.SqlServerTypes, and one of the measures we've taken is to add this to the web.config or app.config file to make sure that the right version of the dll is targeted.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference Microsoft.SqlServer.Types and set "Copy Local" in its Properties. Should help.